# Apple Bluetooth Keyboard support in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth

Am much closer following this 'recipe' (3rd answer) and also cross referencing Arch wiki

https://askubuntu.com/questions/73031...nnect-in-15-10

Only change so far is had to use

```
sudo apt-get install bluez:i386
```

to get bluetoothctl

ok so works initially BUT
after reboot NO bluetooth icon in my Panel and bluetooth not working

Also if I try and duplicate the install I get

> [bluetooth]# scan on Failed to start discovery:
>   org.bluez.Error.NotReady

result of [bluetooth]# show

> Controller 5C:F3:70:7D:3D:BC Name: Art3mis Alias: Art3mis Class:
>   0x000000 Powered: no Discoverable: no Pairable: yes UUID: Generic
>   Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb) UUID: A/V
>   Remote Control (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb) UUID: PnP
>   Information (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb) UUID: Generic
>   Access Profile (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb) UUID: A/V Remote
>   Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb) Modalias:
>   usb:v1D6Bp0246d0525 Discovering: no

result of systemctl status bluetooth:

> bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service Loaded: loaded
>   (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset Active:
>   active (running) since Tue 2017-01-10 09:52:19 EST; 10min ago Docs:
>   man:bluetoothd(8) Main PID: 9221 (bluetoothd) Status: "Running"
>   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service └─9221
>   /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
>
> Jan 10 09:52:19 Art3mis bluetoothd[9221]: Not enough free handles to
>   register se Jan 10 09:52:19 Art3mis bluetoothd[9221]: Not enough free
>   handles to register se Jan 10 09:52:19 Art3mis bluetoothd[9221]: Not
>   enough free handles to register se Jan 10 09:52:19 Art3mis
>   bluetoothd[9221]: Current Time Service could not be regi Jan 10
>   09:52:19 Art3mis bluetoothd[9221]: gatt-time-server: Input/output
>   error ( Jan 10 09:52:19 Art3mis bluetoothd[9221]: Not enough free
>   handles to register se Jan 10 09:52:19 Art3mis bluetoothd[9221]: Not
>   enough free handles to register se Jan 10 09:52:19 Art3mis
>   bluetoothd[9221]: Sap driver initialization failed. Jan 10 09:52:19
>   Art3mis bluetoothd[9221]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1 Jan
>   10 09:52:19 Art3mis systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service

hcitool scan

> Device is not available: No such device

Any bluetooth experts reading this that can help?